# Retrieve a sha256 from another sha256

Tags: c, sha256

I have a project where we are supposed to find a sha256 from another sha256.

For example we have

```
hash1 = "45f1bc22c29626c6db37d483273afbe0f6c434de02fe86229d50c9e71ed144fc"
```

and we would have to find

```
hash0 = "5495a885b7f445a198cc5b67a517a0e0536792ab3e7ead18a12c75f8310a9b89"
```

`hash1` is just the `hash0` used in a sha256 function.

Initially, I went on to redo every possibility of sha256 but it may do a lot and take a lot of time.
If you have any idea how I could do this, even see if it's possible?

Comment: it's not a "it may do a lot and take a lot of time", it is a "it will take all the time humanity will be alive in the universe" the point of sha256 is to be a 1 way function with no knowledge of the original. Is there any more information you can give because right now this looks like half of a homework assignment.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about you project, because this looks like an XY-problem.

Comment: There is not really any information beyond what I have given.
We have a list of sha256, which are just "infinity hash" sha256
For example hash1 is hash, then this hash is rehash.
Couldn't we try to split the hash by chance to find a part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible, hashes can't be inverted, regardless if they're hashes of hashes or of other content. You could try all the combinations, sure, knowing that the source is a 256-bit sequence, but this is practically prohibitive, although there's always a possibility of 1 out of 2^256 that you guess it at the first try :-)